# How is the receptive field of a CNN affected by transposed convolution?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

When computing receptive field recursively through a CNN, does a transposed convolution affect the receptive field the same way that a convolution does if the kernel and stride is the same?